# How to model game theory of poker-like card game

Tags: games, game-theory

I'd like to get a general understanding of the optimal strategy from a game called [Team Fight Tactics](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/events/teamfight-tactics). To reduce this problem into a simpler form I'd like to analyze a simpler card game problem I've made up:

> Suppose a game exists where N players compete against each other in
>   rounds.
>
> Each round consists of three phases: drawing two random cards
>   from a single shared deck, selecting a single card to keep
>   (reinserting the other randomly back into the deck), and finally
>   competing against a random opponent.
>
> The player with the higher partial poker hand wins--that is, a poker
>   hand that does not require exactly 5 cards. Consequently, if a player
>   loses three rounds, then they are eliminated from the game.
>
> Assuming each player plays optimally, what is the optimal strategy to win 
>   first place?

Despite my lack of knowledge in the subject matter, I'd like to try to study some papers or get a direction toward approaching this topic. The main focus I am trying to understand is the decision making behind selecting a card over another.

Comment: Why do you use the term "nonparametric" here?

Comment: @Glen_b I used the term nonparametric because I felt unit compositions success in`Team Fight Tactics` as well as poker hands based on composition / card ranking rather than the value of the cards themselves. Consequently, the value of selecting a two is not expected to have a gaussian distribution as it depends on current cards, and how it matches to make other sets.

Comment: Distributions that arise in answering the questions you have won't be normal (except perhaps as approximations), but *[parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics)* does not  mean "has a Gaussian distribution". Instead it relates to the number of parameters needed to describe the distributional model (whether that's fixed and finite). One example of a parametric distributional model that arises in many card problems would be the hypergeometric distribution. If you're using "nonparametric" in your searches it's likely to prevent you from finding anything useful.

Comment: @Glen_b Ok I see, I think in my cursory research I misused the term. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: This misunderstanding of what distinction is being made by parametric / non-parametric isn't your fault -- a number of basic books written for people in several application areas get this concept quite wrong (ultimately leading to them giving poor advice - such as 'if you don't have normality, you have to use nonparametric statistics'). This misinformation is then repeated in many places.

Comment: I think this fits in the area of Reinforcement Learning so you should probably study Markov Decision Processes and so on...

Comment: Wait, each player was dsitributed two cards of which he returned one, ending up with one. Where do the poker hands come from? 
You need to be more precise.